# Cannot disable Display Port via grub boot options

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr, displayport

When I run `xrandr` on the terminal I see `DVI-0 connected` and `DisplayPort-1 connected`. I only use `DVI-0` as my output. I don't have two screens, or anything else connected to my computer, so I don't know why `DisplayPort-1` is even presented. I use an HDMI to DVI adapter..

Since `DisplayPort-1` is presented, I am getting some weird behavior when changing the resolution. If I run `xrandr -s 1024x768` and I was previously in a resolution of `800x600`, then I will get a cut off screen because for some reason I'm changing the resolution of the DisplayPort. This also happens going the other way, from `1024x768` to `800x600`.

In the past I would add `video=DP-1:d` to the grub boot options to hide this "phantom" display. This would fix all the funny problems. However, this grub option no longer works! After adding it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` and doing an `update-grub`, the computer still comes up with the phantom `DisplayPort-1` output.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify what is fixed and your video card ?

Comment: When I add "video=DP-1:d", then I can change the resolution from 800x600 to 1024x768 without any screen-cut offs. The only output device I see when I do xrandr is then DVI-0 which is what I would expect, because that's the only device that is plugged in. I don't even have a DisplayPort!

Comment: Here is a link to the output ( http://pastebin.com/AdDnfBuF ) of lshw and my video card:  

*-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller

Comment: Looks like a gma500 . What graphics problem are you having ? should have native resolution (1366x786)

Comment: I was able to disable the display port by adding "video=DP-2:d" to the grub boot options. This fixed MY problem.

Comment: @Gabe You should post an answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to disable the display port by adding `video=DP-2:d` to the grub boot options. Notice that `xrandr` was showing `DisplayPort-1` even though in reality `DP-2` was enabled.

Here's how I was able to find out which was the real output device thanks to the [ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_mode_setting):

*To get the name and current status of connectors, you can use the following shell one-liner:

```
$ for p in /sys/class/drm/*/status; do con=${p%/status}; echo -n "${con#*/card?-}: "; cat $p; done

DVI-I-1: connected
HDMI-A-1: disconnected
VGA-1: disconnected
```

Comment: Can you post your XRANDR output. I want to understand why we need to add DP-2:d